# File System access from Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox-addon

Is it possbile to create a firefox extendsion to write to files in a windows file system ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I/O) for examples.

**Edit**

XPCOM and so `nsIFile` are now legacy technologies :

> Use of [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm) is preferred over the examples in this article. Only use these legacy interfaces if OS.File is not available to you.

You can find the new way to go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm)

Comment: mozilla will be deprecating XPCOM and therefore the nsIFile so this will very soon be irrelevant.

Comment: Note that this is still valid for Thunderbird, which is *not* (at least not yet) deprecating/removing "legacy" extensions. In addition, there are various forks of Firefox in which "legacy" extensions are still valid.