# Is it possible to access Win API from Firefox/Internet Explorer toolbar extention?

Tags: winapi, internet-explorer, firefox, toolbar

We have an idea to develop a toolbar for major browsers on Windows.

The toolbar will be a compliment for our weather application.
We want the toolbar to have an access to Windows API, specifically we need Registry and file system access (want access main app user settings).
Is it possible with Firefox and Internet Explorer toolbar extentions?

Browser toolbar development is new grounds for me.
I just want to know if it makes sense to start the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the registry and filesystem from Firefox using the existing XPCom interfaces that are already exposed for you.

Internet Explorer plug-ins are all native, so you're already writing Win32 and COM, so you just call whatever API you need.  However, since you are most likely running in a low integrity process, you need to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which will explain the limitations on registry and filesystem access that you will encounter.  If you describe exactly what registry and filesystem locations you're interested in, I can give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem can be accessed from a Firefox extension:
[File System access from Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316708/file-system-access-from-firefox-extension)

I don't know about Internet Explorer, but that seems like it would make sense.

As for Registry access in Firefox, see this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/accessing_the_windows_registry_using_xpcom

It sounds like it should all be possible.  I didn't find anything about Internet Explorer, but it seems like that would be a feature that they would include.  I don't like to mess with the registry since that is not cross-platform, but if you really need the user settings, then I guess you have a valid reason.  Just remember that not all of your users will be using Windows, and Mac OS doesn't have a registry (neither does Linux), so try not to restrict yourself too much if you can avoid it.