# File select dialog - javascript security issue: easiest(!) way to automatize file selection in Chrome. Very creative solutions may do as well

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, automation, selection

I'm dealing with a very annoying website where you want to upload lots of files there, but you can only do it one file at a time (one per tab).

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I would like to automatize the process of manually opening 40+ tabs and selecting one file for each tab.

The part where I open tabs is easy and it already works, but automatically selecting local files is a problem. I'm well aware that chrome doesn't allow to set `value` for `<input>` tags where `<input type="file">` and I'm looking for a workaround.

I'm looking for the **easiest/less effort solution** to circumvent it.

I was even thinking about simulating clicks outside of my web browser instead of trying to fix it from within Javascript (there are os level script languages for that, but I'm not sure which one would be fastest to learn or which one would need the least number of code lines for my task) or altering the dialog to multiselection (who knows, maybe the website will surprise me and work anyway).

Does anyone know an unconventional but easy solution?

*Edit: I tried setting the input to multiselection with*

`upladbtn.setAttribute("multiple", "true");`

*It didn't work. The website must hve interpreted both files as one single file stream because it displayed a file size error after uploading.*

Comment: You want to write a Chrome extension.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by Google Chrome Plugin. I'm developing one. maybe I should edit my question a little. It doesn't really say that I do.

Comment: Can at least someone tell me which script language they would recommend? Before I abandoned windows many years ago, I used AutoIt. I remember having ended up reading pixel values and it was not a very nice experience. Now that I'm linux user, I was thinking about xdotool. Is that worth getting into?

Comment: Chrome Extensions (you don't want to write a plugin) are written in Javascript.

Comment: It seems that javascript can't achieve that, I was hoping it could (at least there was no answer here until now). So I'm thinking running a script outside of my plugin.

Comment: Javascript can't achieve what, exactly?

Comment: Dude, I know they are written in Javascript >:( First I thought I didn't explain myself properly and tried to stay polite, but I think you simply don't understand my problem and try to answer anyway. Javascript does not allow for automatic selection of local files which are to be uploaded via the "input" html element. At least not without any hacks. I'm looking for those hacks (they should be as simple but also as reliable as possible) or other means (that might go beyond Javascript) to achieve my goal.

Comment: I thought an extension would be able to do it, but I was wrong.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13313026/34397