# How do I upload a file without showing Openfiledialog on webbrowser vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

help with webbrowser!
How do I upload a file without showing Openfiledialog?
I made an example in imacros(Firefox) and I throw this code
`TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE ATTR=* CONTENT=C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MP3\audios\IdiomaC_9179192217_20150703-000023-all.mp3`
How can I send this instruction from vb.net?
It's very important, thank you very much

i cant use imacros api for .net because it to work I have to use an own browser of imacros, and for other functions that I use to not work in the imacros browser, only in the own of vs (WebBrowser)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bypassing the browse file / upload file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313026/bypassing-the-browse-file-upload-file-dialog)

Comment: Why don't you use HttpWebRequest instead of WebBrowser ?

Comment: how can I do it? The website is https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

I do not know about the issue of httprequest and what I have seen I did not understand very well